# What are the health concerns with using a laptop on your lap?

Tags: side-effects, fertility, coloration-discoloration, infertile

I've always wondered why people say I should not put my laptop my lap while using it without telling me why, until I found out that it leads to male infertility and skin discoloration.

Are there any other major side effects of putting my laptop on my lap while using it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main energy emissions (i.e. ways of affecting its surroundings) of a laptop computer are—

- **Sound**: Unless your laptop has extravagant bass speakers that can physically rattle your organs hard enough to be painful, this will have no effect.
- **Heat**: A laptop can run quite hot, and [heating the testes can be used as a method of contraception](http://malecontraceptives.org/methods/heat_biology.php), as the ideal temperature for sperm to survive is a little lower than your body temperature otherwise.  The effect is not permanent—heat strong enough to cause lasting damage would be physically painful.

  However, I think the effect of a laptop on the user's testes is likely to be negligible.  A usual sitting position puts lots of room between the testes and the laptop, allowing most of the heat to dissipate (see [inverse-square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law)).  If you are trying to conceive, and your laptop runs very hot, and you use it in your lap for a large part of your waking hours, *then* its positioning may be worth considering.
- **Radio waves**: Computers use low-power non-ionising radiation for WiFi communication channels.  Such radiation has [not been shown to damage human tissue in any way](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/are-wifi-waves-harmful).

  Cutting-edge devices with a wireless charging feature also receive low frequency radiation from a base station.  [This radiation is also non-ionising and safe](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31385/is-wireless-charging-harmful).

I see no way a laptop could cause skin discoloration, except unless ⓐ the skin was burned because the laptop was hot, or ⓑ if the skin's blood supply was cut off due to long-lasting pressure from a very heavy laptop in the same position.

---

In summary, the only health concern with having a laptop in your lap is *heat*.  Treat a hot laptop like any other hot object: carefully!